# Как бы "разблокировать" и сделать доступным для редактирования .java файл в IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Недавно начал пользоваться IDEA, столкнулся с интересным вопросом (по крайней мере для меня). Искал ответ по поисковым системам, но так и не нашёл что-либо толковое. Возможно неправильно формулирую свой вопрос (скорее всего).

[image: Снимок с рабочего стола]

Вот всё, что смог выяснить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Права супер-админа не помогают, как не менял атрибут на "чтение и редактирование", хоть на "приказывайте что хотите Господин" меняй.

Comment: Печально, придётся качать и работать над OpenJDK, но спасибо, приблизительно понял что вы имели ввиду.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы хотите странного. Исходные коды библиотек и JRE вам IDEA показывает для отладки и для чтения, а не для редактирования. Жаждете что-то поменять - пересоберите библиотеку или OpenJDK соответственно.

Главный подводный камень в том, что вы пытаетесь реализовать (изменение классов JRE): ваше приложение будет работать так, как вы ожидаете только на вашей модифицированной JVM. У всех остальных - по-другому.

Более правильный способ - реализовать дочерний класс, если это возможно.

Answer (score 3):

В правом нижнем углу окна есть значок замка. Надо нажать его.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то не реагирует эта кнопочка, странно.. от чего такое может быть по вашему? Есть какие-то предположения?

Comment: Возможно, у вас нет прав на редактирование этого файла.

Comment: Не смотря на то, что я запустил IDEA как супер-админ? Хм, вот это поворот. А где посмотреть кто имеет права на редактирование? Если такое вообще есть, на что очень надеюсь, может что-то да получится.

Comment: Операционная система какая?

Comment: Arch Linux, хотя супер-админские права не дают привилегий уровня "Бог", но всё же, наверное у Java файлов есть внутренняя система прав что-ли.

Comment: Ну или файл "частично криптованый", такое возможно? Только странно тогда, что могу прочесть весь код, при том без возможности в него как-то вписать свою строчку.

Comment: Исходные тексты - это обычные текстовые файлы. Выполните в консоли команду `ls -l` в каталоге с исходниками и посмотрите какие права доступа выставлены и кто владелец файла.

Comment: Я владелец и права доступа есть у меня, несколько раз проверил и попытался как-то всё же разблокировать этот файл. Только наткнулся на интересную проблему. Вообще, это файл JDK 8, как бы путь к Applet.class следующий (попутал расширение с самого начала, тут Class Заблокирован): jdk1.8.0_73/jre/lib\rt.jar!/java/applet/Applet.class

Comment: Там поставлено "только чтение" даже для root, изменю это на "чтение и редактирование", перезапущу IDEA и гляну, будет ли действовать.

Comment: Всё работает! Спасибо за внимание тов. Сергей.

Comment: Чёрт, показалось что заработало. Но это была иллюзия, как бы там вроде нашёл "зелёненький замочек", но он касался Public Class - но ничуть не редактирования. Файл можно читать и править, но как бы в IDEA нельзя... странно это, очень даже.

Comment: @冬直枝 IDEA не даст вам править исходники JDK, и для чего это вам нужно?

Answer (score 0):

На на Саму запись только для чтения, прям открытом проекте нажать правой кнопкой мыши появляется шоу context actions showcontex axon нажать, далее выбрать либо run main.main, либо debug....и ап, все работает пишем...

Другой вариант, при создании, наверное сти на проект, Правая мышь, снять галочку, только для чтения

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).